# STDOUT redirected externally and no output seen at the console

Tags: perl

I have a program which reads the output from external application.The external app gives set of output. My program reads the output from this external app `while($line=<handle to external app>)` and print it to STDOUT.But the "`print $line STDOUT`" prints only some lines and when the error has occurred ,print to STDOUT is not working , but my one more logging statement "`push @arr,$line`" has stored complete output from the external app.From this i got to know STDOUT is not working properly when error happens.

Eg:
if external app output is like:

---

```
Starting command
First command executed successfully    
Error:123 :next command failed    
Program terminated
```

---

In here the `STDOUT` prints only :

```
Starting command
First command executed successfully
```

But if I check the array it has complete output including error details. So I guessed `STDOUT` has been redirected or lost.

So I tried storing `STDOUT` in the beginning of the program to `$old_handle using` open and then try to restore it before print statement using `select($old_handle)` (thinking some thing redirects STDOUT when error happens)

But I was not successfull, I don't know what is wrong here. Please help me.

Comment: Why is this question community wiki? some people might be discouraged from answering because upvotes will not give them any reputation.

Answer (score 1):

It's possible the output is being buffered. Try setting

```
$| = 1;
```

at the start of your program. This will cause the output to be displayed straight away, rather than being buffered for later.

Comment: hi , i have flushed the buffer also

Answer (score 0):

Just guess, may be because error output doesn't go to STDOUT. Use redirect

```
first_program |& perl_program
```

or

```
first_program 2>&1 | perl_program
```